# calculate the time diffrence between two time in minutes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

using below code to find difference between two times in minutes by using `Datediff()` function but seems it is not working in VBA code. Using this code `=DateDiff(E2, B2)*1440`. but not working. Can anyone help me out in this context. My time comes with date and time.
Example :-

```
Stop date as 07-08-2020 12:15:00 
Start Date as 07-08-2020 11:18:00

Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=DateDiff(E2, B2)*1440"
```

I will be thankful if you can help me.

Regards,
Amit Singh

Comment: can you show what's in E2, B2 cells? to avoid confusion
Also what the current result? what you expect to see instead?

Answer (score 1):

Seems awfully complicated to get your desired result.

Excel stores date/times as days and fractions of a day.

Why not simply:

```
=(stop_date-Start_date) * 1440
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateDiff` isn't a worksheet function, it is an inbuilt VBA function.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function

Try

```
Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = DateDiff("n", [E2], [B2])
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The function in Excel is `=datedif` not `=datediff` I would also suggest using the the VBA `datediff` function as the Excel function is deprecated and there are known issues.

To use the VBA datediff change the code to the following:

`Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = DateDiff("n", [E2], [B2])`

If you have to use an Excel function:-

`Range("I2:I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=(E2-B2)*1440"`